# How can I autoupdate events in google calendar from sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I have a script that generates an event when a form response is submitted. But I also want it to update an event by adding an email as a guest, if the event is at the same time.

I think I need to add an If statement and go that route but I'm not sure thanks for all your help

I followed a tutorial to get this far and it is: [Turn a google form response into a calendar event](http://www.jessespevack.com/blog/2016/2/9/turn-a-google-form-response-into-a-calendar-event)

my code:

```
//Load the Moment.js library once.
var moment = Moment.load();
var GLOBAL = {
  //the id of the form we will use to create calendar events 
  formId : ("1SfePtYKkseN3Pzdy0wxqVoStKMCJuijW9NT0W9aI1qQ"),
  //the id of the calendar we will create events on
  calendarId : "processing@marketingmobileads.com",

  //a mapping of form item titles to sections of the calendar event
  formMap : {
    eventTitle: "Event Title",
    startTime : "Start",
    endTime: "End",
    email: "Email Address",
  },
}
function onFormSubmit() {
  var eventObject = getFormResponse();
  var event = createCalendarEvent(eventObject);
}
function getFormResponse() {
  // Get a form object by opening the form using the
  // form id stored in the GLOBAL variable object
  var form = FormApp.openById(GLOBAL.formId),
      //Get all responses from the form. 
      //This method returns an array of form responses
      responses = form.getResponses(),
      //find the length of the responses array
      length = responses.length,
      //find the index of the most recent form response
      //since arrays are zero indexed, the last response 
      //is the total number of responses minus one
      lastResponse = responses[length-1],
      //get an array of responses to every question item 
      //within the form for which the respondent provided an answer
      itemResponses = lastResponse.getItemResponses(),
      //create an empty object to store data from the last form response
      //that will be used to create a calendar event
      eventObject = {};
  //Loop through each item response in the item response array
  for (var i = 0, x = itemResponses.length; i<x; i++) {
    //Get the title of the form item being iterated on
    var thisItem = itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle(),
        //get the submitted response to the form item being
        //iterated on
        thisResponse = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
    //based on the form question title, map the response of the 
    //item being iterated on into our eventObject variable
    //use the GLOBAL variable formMap sub object to match 
    //form question titles to property keys in the event object
    switch (thisItem) {
      case GLOBAL.formMap.eventTitle:
        eventObject.title = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.startTime:
        eventObject.startTime = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.endTime:
        eventObject.endTime = thisResponse;
        break; 
      case GLOBAL.formMap.email:
        eventObject.email = thisResponse;
        break;
    }
  }
  return eventObject;
}
function createCalendarEvent(eventObject) {
  //Get a calendar object by opening the calendar using the
  //calendar id stored in the GLOBAL variable object
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(GLOBAL.calendarId),
      //The title for the event that will be created
      title = eventObject.title,
      //The start time and date of the event that will be created
      startTime = moment(eventObject.startTime).toDate(),
      //The end time and date of the event that will be created
      endTime = moment(eventObject.endTime).toDate();
      //an options object containing the description and guest list
      //for the event that will be created
  var options = {
      guests : eventObject.email,
  };
  try {
    //create a calendar event with given title, start time,
    //end time, and description and guests stored in an 
    //options argument
    var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)
  } catch (e) {
    //delete the guest property from the options variable, 
    //as an invalid email address with cause this method to 
    //throw an error.
    delete options.guests
    //create the event without including the guest
    var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)
  }
  return event;   
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. For example, where is the email you want to include coming from? What event is to be updated?

Comment: Also note that if you change your function title from `onFormSubmit` to `onFormSubmit(e)`, you can access the event object it provides. depending where this script project is bound (to the form or to the responses sheet), the event object is slightly different: [`Form` version](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_3) vs [`Sheets` version](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: the email is coming from the spreadsheet and the event is being made from the information from the sheet, here is link, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Oe4uq9BCYzI0tEgwv9NMEj_KK0-3m0__eFO-ab5afY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It is an webinar registration form that people can sign up for using the form. The data is then sent to the spreadsheet where a script uses the info to make an event. The script works but makes additional events even if they happen for the same webinar. So I want to modify the script to make an event if there is none present, but if there is already an event made then add the additional person as a guest.

Comment: Sounds like you first need to implement an event lookup. You can do that any number of ways, the simplest of which is to query the calendar. If you get an event that matches (you'll have to define how to know if that event matches, maybe the same name and location, etc), then it sounds like you need to register a new attendee. The Apps Script documentation should have this information readily available.